# android: How to create file under android-2.3.7?

Tags: java, android, file

I can't find anywhere how to properly create a new file in android 2.3.7 (Cyanogenmod).

Normal code just doesn't work, throws IOException or FileNotFoundException:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/gpx/";
//There is a gpx folder in my sdcard, the app can read those files but can't create a new one.

File file = new File(path, filename);
//if i insert file.createNewFile(); the app throws "IOException: Invalid argument" but does not crash.
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
String data = "somedata";
fos.write(data.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

The outputstream is public. When the service stops, the final data is written by another methond from onDestroy(). That crashes the app in that method on line fos.write(endtag.getbytes()); The error is NullPointerException.

As I understand the previous code does not create the file output stream because of failing to create the file. If anyone knows, WHAT IS THE "IOException: Invalid argument". What is that invalid argument? I think I don't understand the problem which is somewhere maybe? Is there some additional parameters needed when creating the file in that version of android? On android 4.+ it works fine.

Can anyone give some basic example how to create the file on sdcard in that old version of android or explain what is the "Invalid argument" in IOException?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found what was wrong. In this question I forgot to mention, that the filename used was a date with format `"yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss"` so the problem was the ":" symbol which I suggest was not allowed in filename in android 2.3.7.

Simply fixing format to `"yyyy-mm-dd HH-mm-ss"` solved the problem which was such a pain.